# How to see database from a POST request?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, graphql

I'm working on an app in Ruby on Rails with GraphQL API. Our database is MySQL.

In my test file, I have a POST request to a staging site for our app: `post "https://apistaging.app.com/graphql"`

Is there a way to see the database and tables from this request? Like is there a way to execute `SELECT * FROM table` from this request? Or can I only use queries and mutations defined in my schema? I would like to see the data on the staging site, since my mutations aren't working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, and you definitely don't want to do this in production, but you could probably get away with using the `find_by_sql` clause to do a search against a completely different table

```
 Determinand.find_by_sql('select tests.* from tests where "SHORTNAME" like \'Shipping\'').count
  Determinand Load (0.7ms)  select tests.* from tests where "SHORTNAME" like 'Shipping'
=> 7
```

Do not do this in production though, as the class of the objects is based on the class of the originating object, which causes debugging nightmares:

```
Determinand.find_by_sql('select tests.* from tests where "SHORTNAME" like \'Shipping\'').first.class
 => Determinand(id: integer, ...
```

Comment: so is there a better way to test for data from POST? Because I'm testing a sign in mutation and I can sign in on Altair, but I can't replicate the mutation successfully in a test file

Comment: run the database in development mode and check the output in the logs? or set up `byebug` and then get access to the data in the console when byebug activates?  my answer "gets around" your issue of needed a class to access an object in a table that isn't modelled, but it doesn't get you past your underlying problem if you're mutating